# Loop is Getting Stuck on First Interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I realise some of you will spot this in a second but for some reason I cant get the loop to cycle more than the initital loop, when hitting the button with the onclick command.

```
//creat array with my questions
var qArray = [
  'What is the answer to the sum 1 + 1?',
  'If I have two eggs and I drop one how many do I have left?',
  'What are the three primary     colors?'
];

//create variables
var counter = 0;
var theQuestions = document.getElementById('theQuestions');

//loop through array
function questFunc() {
    for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[i];
        counter++;
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated it. I had a look around but cant find it, Im sure it's because its such an obvious fix/dumb mistake :D

Thank you..

Comment: I think the variable `count` in your loop is wrong. Maybe you mean `counter`?

Comment: The counter seems somewhat irrelevant, but the `innerHTML` is overwritten on every iteration, every time the function is called, it doesn't really change ?

Comment: sorry ignore the counter, you're write, it had a typo but the function still doesnt work.  When I click the button in the html I want to cycle through the questions, each time I click it shows another question. Until it hits the last. At the moment it jumps to the last one.     HTML button-->    <button onclick="questFunc()">Submit</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fo`r loop worked as expected, the first issue was in this row: `theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[i];`. Every time when you changed `innerHTML`, it didn't add one more item, it just overwrote the previous value with new one, so you can try to use `append()` instead. The second issue is using `for` loop in your case, this way you looped through whole array by only one button click. You already have `counter` variable to store an array index that will be used after next button click. May be it's not very good explanation, but feel free to ask more questions.

And a snippet:

```js
//creat array with my questions
var qArray = ['What is the answer to the sum 1 + 1?', 'If I have two eggs and I drop one how many do I have left?', 'What are the three primary     colors?'];

//create variables
var counter = 0;
var theQuestions = document.getElementById('theQuestions');

//loop through array
function questFunc() {
    if (counter < qArray.length) {
      theQuestions.append(qArray[counter]);
      counter ++;
    }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="questFunc()">Click</button>
<div id="theQuestions"></div>
```

And here is how it works with `innerHTML`:

```js
//creat array with my questions
var qArray = ['What is the answer to the sum 1 + 1?', 'If I have two eggs and I drop one how many do I have left?', 'What are the three primary     colors?'];

//create variables
var counter = 0;
var theQuestions = document.getElementById('theQuestions');

//loop through array
function questFunc() {
    if (counter < qArray.length) {
      theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[counter];
      counter ++;
    }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="questFunc()">Click</button>
<div id="theQuestions"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this didnt seem to work. I wonder as well why did you call it at the end? Was that just for the same of the snippet, as you dont have the html i have (IE button to click)?

Comment: @11-, Hi. *"you dont have the html i have"* - that's right. *"unfortunately this didnt seem to work"* - all three array items were appended, isn't it what you tried to achieve? If so, please say, what is the expected result.

Comment: Sorry I havent been as clear as I thought. I want a question to appear each loop (every time I click my html button).

Comment: @11-, easy, I have updated the answer. Is it an expected result?

Comment: yes  thanks that's what I want to achieve but what im not grasping is why my loop wasnt working. What was making it loop through the whole array?

Comment: @11-, the `for` loop worked as expected, the first issue was in this row: `theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[i];`. Every time when you changed `innerHTML`, it didn't add one more item, it just overwrote the previous value with new one. The second issue is using `for` loop  in your case, this way you looped through whole array by only one button click. You already have `counter` variable to store an array index that will be used after next button click. May be it's not very good explanation, but feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Could you try explain why ...theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[i];... doesnt work, but ...theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[counter];... does? This has been a great help btw. Big thanks to all so far!

Comment: @11-, no, `theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[counter];` will not work too. `innerHTML` and `append` are working differently, in your case you need `append`, use it like this: `theQuestions.append(qArray[counter]);`.

Comment: That doesnt replace it, it seems. Each time I click its adding a question not replacing it.

Comment: @11-, no, it replaces, believe me ;) . No, don't believe me, check out the updated answer (I have added another snippet at the bottom which uses `innerHTML`)

Comment: Sorry but if i press the click button on the snippet 3 times i end up with all the questions on the page. Im after just one at a time.

Comment: @11-, I mean this snippet at the bottom: https://snag.gy/phO2aC.jpg. Click "show code snippet" and then run it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show a new question on every time you click on the button. You could try the following:

```
//creat array with my questions
var qArray = ['What is the answer to the sum 1 + 1?', 'If I have two eggs and I drop one how many do I have left?', 'What are the three primary     colors?'];

//create variables
var counter = 0;
var theQuestions = document.getElementById('theQuestions');

//loop through array
function questFunc() {
    if (counter < qArray.length) {
        theQuestions.innerHTML = qArray[counter];
        counter++;
    }
};
```

Comment: The counter is for the 'question 1/2/3' section. Plus im quite interested in using the 'i' as I assumed using the 'i' in the loop was how you used the looped on the array..

Comment: You said _I want to cycle through the questions, each time I click it shows another question_  So the code above should work for your or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: nope you understood. I just want to know how I do it using the ivariable. I'm sorry, I am trying to understand it not just fix it.

Comment: You can replace the variable `counter` by any variable you like. The important thing ist that the variable is declared outside of `questFunc()` because it's value must be retained.

Comment: The idea is that `questFunc` will run when you click the button. so you don't want to loop through all questions every time the button is clicked.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't process all questions at the time. You need to leave the function after you have set one question text.